# Java - Escape a character

Tags: java, escaping

```
String[] ln = read.nextLine().split("\\.");
```

Why do i have to escape the **`.`** ? I thought i have already defined it as a String with `""` and it is not separator anymore.

Comment: You are splitting on a regular expression and if you want to use any of the special characters literally you need to escape them out.

Comment: If you were escaping it out for a string like `"\""` you would only need one \ however if you want escape out for the regex you need two. Note if you want a \ in the regex you need to write `"\\\\"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) as a parameter. The symbol `.` has a special meaning in regular expressions, meaning "match any character". Using backslashes, you can escape its regular expression meaning and match it as an ordinary character. Or as OldCurmudgeon pointed out, the recommended way to fully escape a regular expression is to use [`Pattern.quote(".")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: May like to add that it is recommended to use `Pattern.quote(".")`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Good idea